# Unable to paginate with node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

So in my server I have:

```
app.get('/getposts/:pageno', (req, res) => {

  let pageno = req.params.pageno

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ? , 3', [pageno], function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        res.send(rows);

        console.log(pageno);
    });

});
```

And when I try to access it like: `http://localhost:3000/getposts/2`

I get error:

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2' , 3'

 code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
\'\'2\' , 3\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT \'2\' , 3' }
```

`pageno` is logged in the console. I'm passing the first parameter of the LIMIT as `?` `[pageno]` as described in their [official notes](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) If I type `2` or any other number in the `LIMIT 2,3`, it works. I have over a thousand dummy records in the table.

Also tried 
`var sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ' + connection.escape(pageno) + ', 3';`
and used `sql` in `connection.query` but same error.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Error says it prints as \'2\' . What did you get when you printed? Can you try parseInt() for the pageno

Comment: That worked! I did  `var newPageNo = parseInt(pageno)` and used `newPageNo` instead and it worked. What was the issue? When I did `console.log(pageno)` I was getting a pure `int`.

Comment: Glad it worked I can&amp;#39;t say the exact reason without checking the whole code, I mean how the data is coming and which npm you are using etc. But it is always a good practice to use the correct types. Return a failed response if it is not a numeric value. Please mark this as resolved.

Comment: GET parameter values are always strings (because a query string "is" just text, there is no mechanism to specify any _type_ of value), any application using strict typing needs to convert them itself if necessary. Your database class apparently automatically checks the type of the given parameter, and inserts it into the SQL query it generates accordingly.

Comment: _"When I did console.log(pageno) I was getting a pure int."_ - did it actually say "int(eger)" anywhere? Don't know about the node.js console, but at least in Chromium on the client-side, `console.log("2", 2);` just results in `2 2`, the first one in black and the second one in blue ... doubt I would notice the "difference" if I saw only either one value.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC how do I mark this as resolved? There is no answer. Only your comment. Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `parseInt()` for the page number.